# Can we detect browsers refresh and back button events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Anybody know how to detect browsers refresh and back button events in firefox using jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 5):

For back button:

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) {
//Your code here
});
```

For Refresh:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
 // Your code here
}
```

Comment: popstate fires on both forwards and backwards button presses.

Comment: onbeforeunload fires any time the page unloads - upon closing, navigating, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.onbeforeunload):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {

};
```

and

```
$(window).unload(function() {
      //
});
```

Also check [Browser Back Button Detection](http://www.bajb.net/2010/02/browser-back-button-detection/):

> I have made a very reusable javascript class, that can be simply
>   dropped into your web page, and when the user clicks back, it will
>   call a function. The default function on this call is a javascript
>   alert “Back Button Clicked”.
>
> To replace this functionality, you simply need to override the OnBack
>   function. This can be done by using the code below.
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> bajb_backdetect.OnBack = function()
> {
> alert('You clicked it!');
> }
> </script>
> ```
>
> This will now replace the “Back Button Clicked” alert with a “You
>   clicked it!’” alert.

Answer (score 1):

Check this page: [Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

You can probably get something working with using `history.pushState` and `window.onpopstate`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following events:

`window.onpopstate` for back button press.

```
window.onpopstate = (e) => {
  // your logic goes here
};
```

`window.onbeforeunload` for refresh or tab close.

```
window.onbeforeunload = (e) => {
  // your logic here
  e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = 'There are unsaved changes. Sure you want to leave?';
};
```